# Android Realm iterators exception

Tags: android, iterator, realm

Android Realm, I want to code like this:

```
public void updateChecked(MyModel model) {
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().beginTransaction();
    model.setChecked(true);
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().commitTransaction();
}

public void updateAllChecked() {
    RealmResults<MyModel> results = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(MyModel.class).findAll();
    for (MyModel model : results) {
        updateChecked(model);
    }
}
```

with error when I call updateAllChecked():

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: No outside changes to a Realm is allowed while iterating a RealmResults. Use iterators methods instead.
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change objects during iteration. You need first manually copy all objects to another list and then iterate over them

```java
List<MyModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(results);

realm.beginTransaction();
for (MyModel myModel : list){
    myModel.setChecked(true);
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Where is list used? And where does category, categories come from?

Answer (score 1):

Use a good old for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
   MyModel model = results.get(i);
   updateChecked(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this action cannot be made inside a foreach loop, instead you can use the normal for loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        updateChecked( results.get(i))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes in 0.89.0 allow this to happen, but previously the canonical solution was reverse iteration with normal for loop.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
RealmResults<MyModel> results = realm.where(MyModel.class).equalTo("checked", false).findAll();
for(int i = results.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    MyModel myModel = results.get(i);
    myModel.setChecked(true);
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```